# Authorization permissions and UI element visibility - how to implement it cleanly?

Tags: permissions, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, user-experience

I have developed a pretty standard and common authorization permission system for an internal business web application.

There are some roles with permission sets; system administrator can create new roles and assign permissions to them; every web controller method has an attribute to check for specific permission. So far so good.

But then I have the following conversation with the customer:

Customer: "Please, make it possible to hide specific form fields in specific forms for a specific role".

I: "Ok, so the users of this role shouldn't have permissions to modify these fields, right? I can also add a permission check to the method that saves the data."

Customer: "No, no, it's not a permission issue as such, it's just about convenience - this role doesn't need to work with these fields and we want to make the UI less cluttered. The users of this role shouldn't see these fields in this form only; however, there are other forms where it's totally OK to see these fields. Of course, we might later create new roles that will need to see these fields in this form, but by default the fields should be hidden."

And so the permission system gets cluttered with "pseudo-permissions", such as "See field X in form Y". They exist for UI convenience purposes only and have nothing to do with authorization for performing activities on data.

**Is it a good practice to control UI through roles & permissions, even when the specific permission has nothing to do with data processing authorization? Is there a clean solution to avoid cluttering the permission system implementation with such UI-only pseudo-permissions and still provide the customer with granular control to achieve cleaner UI for specific roles?**

Comment: It's perfectly fine and frankly quite normal, especially in enterprise software. We're in an RFP process right now for a new POS system and the ability to control visibility of UI elements by user and role is a core requirement, in fact. As far as complexity goes, ASP.NET Core's support of policies makes life much easier here. See the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/views?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: If its a matter of convenience perhaps a user setting might be more appropriate than a role

Comment: @Shoe - yes, my inner "SRP pedant" tells me that UI-only "permissions" should be separated from actual activity and data processing permissions. Maybe some kind of workspace settings (with sane defaults for a role) might make sense, but I haven't yet seen it implemented in practice. However, I've seen some related functionality in some datagrid components - for example, letting users to hide columns that they don't want to see for some reason. The same approach could be used also for other UI elements.